# Ag grid 'agLargeTextCellEditor' first character lost on input

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using angular and ag-grid. If a user tabs to an 'agLargeTextCellEditor' field and tries to enter text, the first character is used to open the input field and only the second character is recognized. How can I get the first character to be recorded in the input field without having to change the cellEditor property to 'agTextCellEditor'?

Here is an example -

https://plnkr.co/edit/dxS2V2kFYNP523QZZTMP?preview

```
cellEditor: 'agLargeTextCellEditor',
```

If one tabs to any last name field and enters 'to' the value 'to' is recorded on the input field but if one tabs to the address field and enters 'to' the value 'o' is recorded on the input field.

Thanks in advance